# Web view does not load the redirect url

Tags: android, webview

My webview does not work for the urls that redirect to another page. It opens browsers from the app but does not load the webview. Any idea?

The code for webview is:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.simpleWebView);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

if(getIntent().getStringExtra("url")!=null){
    loadLink(getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
}else{
    Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "Please try again later!", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main Class

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private WebView webview;
    private static final String TAG = "Main";
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "WebView Example", "Loading...");

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Your main.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <WebView android:id="@string/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why need to subclass `WebViewClient` and call `loadUrl()` method without using the new object? What's that difference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write what does your loadLink method contain.
Are you sure, that you've implemented it properly - webView.loadUrl(...)?

Answer (score 0):

```
  webView=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
        return view;
    }
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The docs of `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` says:
*Note: Do not call WebView.loadUrl(String) with the same URL and then return true. This unnecessarily cancels the current load and starts a new load with the same URL. The correct way to continue loading a given URL is to simply return false, without calling WebView.loadUrl(String).*
Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewClient.java#40